# Cassandra:What operations do need a restart?

Tags: database, cassandra

When must Cassandra be restarted? for what operations? Anyone got something like a list?

for example:
- when changing a column family definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much just upgrades. Schema changes, cache settings, even subsystems like the snitch can all be changed without a restart.

Comment: what do you mean with upgrades?